# How to process a request to an external REST service and return the response to Google Assistant?

Tags: java, rest, spring-mvc, actions-on-google, google-assist-api

I am using Java to create an app for Google Assistant that will call an external REST API and return certain responses based on trigger phrases.
I currently can use the Default Welcome Intent to return simple text responses through the Actions on Google simulator. However, when I try to call an external REST API and send back a response,  the simulator returns a message that says:

> "MalformedResponse: Failed to parse Dialogflow response into AppResponse because of empty speech response."

I am using the `org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate` from Spring-framework to process the result from the REST Service (https://fitzroi-rest-api-0525.appspot.com/rest/Fitz) with the following call: 
`greeting = restTemplate.getForObject("https://fitzroi-rest-api-0525.appspot.com/rest/{name}", Greeting.class, givenName);` (This works well in a regular Spring project, but not within the Actions on Google Intent)

An example training phrase for my test app is "Tony is sending greetings." From here I am extracting "Tony" as a `@sys.given-name` entity in Dialogflow. This name is then passed to the REST serivice for processing. The REST service is an MVC app that is running in a separate Google Cloud project from the Google Assistant App.

Please let me know if this is a good approach to consume a REST service using Dialogflow fullfillment webhook.

Below is a sample code from my webhook that is trying to consume the REST service.

```java
@ForIntent("process-greeting")
  public ActionResponse greetingProcessor(ActionRequest request) {
    LOGGER.info("Trying to process greeting intent");
    ResponseBuilder responseBuilder = getResponseBuilder(request);

    String givenName = (String) request.getParameter("given-name");


    if (givenName != null && !givenName.isEmpty()) {
      RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
      Greeting greeting = null;
      greeting = restTemplate.getForObject("https://fitzroi-rest-api-0525.appspot.com/rest/{name}", Greeting.class, givenName);

//    LOGGER.info("Attempting to send back " + greeting.getContent() + " to Google Assistant");
      if (greeting == null)
        responseBuilder.add("The rest service did not return a  response.");
      else
        responseBuilder.add(greeting.getContent());
    }

    LOGGER.info("Welcome intent end.");
    return responseBuilder.build();
  }
```

Comment: This doesn't look related to your REST API query. It could be because `givenName` is null. The exception says your speech response is empty. That could only happen when your `if` statement is not triggered (because `givenName` is null or empty). Double check your parameter `givenName` has a value

Comment: Thanks, but no that's not the case. Even if I hard code `givenName` and remove the `if` statement, I still get the same error message. The other thing is that I don't know of a way to debug if greeting ever returns a response in the intent. I can't seem to find where the LOGGER logs in the Simulator. The only logs I have are the simulator logs of messages between the agent and the Assistant.

Comment: Does `greeting` have content? It seems like `greeting` can be both non-null and with empty content

Comment: Getting a value into the `greeting` variable is the main reason for posting this question. That's where the REST call is made, which is not being fulfilled. This line works in a simple Java project, but doesn't work in the Actions on Google app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that since `actions-on-google` requires thread-safe function calls, the `RestTemplate` from `spring-framework` does not work in an `app-engine` app. I was able to find a walk-around by using a sample code provided by the `actions-on-google` team on [GitHub](https://github.com/actions-on-google/dialogflow-quotes-java/). This code requires that you parse the results from the URL from within the `ActionsApp` instead of using a library. For example:

```java
URL restURL = new URL("http://yourdomain.com/your/rest/call");
URLConnection conn = restURL.openConnection();
InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(
               (InputStream) conn.getContent());
JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
JsonElement root = parser.parse(reader);
MyObject = myParseFunction(root);
```

I also had a serious issue (UnKonwnHostException) parsing the results from a remote URL. This [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/issue-requests) was helpful.